# Node.js SSL Cassandra Apache

Tags: node.js, ssl, cassandra

I have a problem with inclusion SSL encryption in the code node.js. I have configured the database but can not connect to the application via SSL. All the time I get an error. Maybe there is someone who has had the same or know what to do because I get tired of the fourth day. I give everything you need.
[image]

```js
client_encryption_options:
    enabled: true
    keystore: E:/apache-cassandra-2.1.4/conf/.keystore
    keystore_password: cassandra
    # require_client_auth: false
    # Set trustore and truststore_password if require_client_auth is true
    # truststore: conf/.truststore
    # truststore_password: cassandra
    # More advanced defaults below:
    # protocol: TLS
    # algorithm: SunX509
    # store_type: JKS
    # cipher_suites: [TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_DHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA,TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA]
```

for generate cert's
https://github.com/PatrickCallaghan/datastax-ssl-example

```js
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert')
var sslOptions = {
    key: fs.readFileSync('server-key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('server-cert.pem'),
 ca: [ fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem') ]
};
var client = new cassandra.Client({
 contactPoints : ['127.0.0.1'],
 authProvider : new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra'),
 sslOptions : sslOptions
});

client.connect(function(err){
 assert.ifError(err);
})
```

[image]

please help

```js
[authentication]
username = cassandra
password = cassandra

[connection]
hostname = 127.0.0.1
port = 9042
factory = cqlshlib.ssl.ssl_transport_factory

[ssl]
certfile = E:/certs/localhost_user1.pem
validate = true ## Optional, true by default.
```

Comment: It looks like the error being thrown is not related to encryption.
If you look at the [source code](https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver/blob/v2.0.1/lib/connection.js#L490), that error is thrown when no callback is defined for an execution. Could you post the rest of the code you are using?

Comment: How do I do them? I do not know how to write code

Comment: I have so much code in the same application, first I wanted to write the database connection

Comment: jorgebg help me, please

Comment: You can enable tracing in the driver with `client.on('log', console.log)` https://github.com/datastax/nodejs-driver#logging . You can try to debugging, without more information it will be difficult to help you. If you want to share your code, use a a code sharing web like gist.github.com

Answer (score 0):

new screenshoots with certyficates .cer and pem
[image]

[image]

```js
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert');
var sslOptions = {
 key : fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
 cert : fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),
 ca : [fs.readFileSync('localhost.cer')]
};
var client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints : ['127.0.0.1'],
  authProvider : new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra'),
  sslOptions : sslOptions
 });

client.connect(function (err) {
 assert.ifError(err);
})
client.on('log', function (level, className, message, furtherInfo) {
 console.log('log event: %s -- %s', level, message);
});
```

[image]