# Cannot connect with cassandra node.js

Tags: node.js, ssl, cassandra, cql

The developers probably do not understand my problem...which lies in the fact that it throws me an error in the file node.js shows that the object is not a function and I do not know how else to set up a javascript file was correct. The error is shown on the 490: 3. What do I have to add javascript file that did not exist error. Please honest answer because I am eager to turn on SSL

```js
var cassandra = require('cassandra-driver');
var fs = require('fs');
var assert = require('assert')
 var sslOptions = {
 key : fs.readFileSync('client-key.pem'),
 cert : fs.readFileSync('client-cert.pem'),
 ca : [fs.readFileSync('server.pem')]
};
var client = new cassandra.Client({
  contactPoints : ['127.0.0.1'],
  authProvider : new cassandra.auth.PlainTextAuthProvider('cassandra', 'cassandra'),
  sslOptions : sslOptions
 });

client.connect(function (err) {
 assert.ifError(err);
})
```

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Node.js SSL Cassandra Apache](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599746/node-js-ssl-cassandra-apache)

Comment: It's the same question as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29599746/node-js-ssl-cassandra-apache , repositing won't help.